# Issues with existing root view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an appDelegate.h like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyViewController *myViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyNavigationController *myNavigationController;
```

I have an appDelegate.m like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    _myNavigationController=[[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_myViewController];
    // self.window.rootViewController = nil;
    self.window.rootViewController = _myNavigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    return YES;
}
```

But if I have my app on my phone and log out after a while, the rootViewController never gets fired. The screen is just black instead of showing my blue background on my myViewController.

Also when the app loads and is logged in, the screen starts black and pushs to my first tab bar.  See details of myViewController.m below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // login code returns currentUser if logged in, otherwise not

    if (currentUser)
    {
        // User is logged in

        TabBarController *mytab = [[TabBarController alloc] init];

        // Hide navigation bar on home page
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        // Presentation
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mytab animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        // The user is not logged in
        [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        [self addLoginButtonsAndViewDetails];
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

(Side note: if the user is logged in, how do I create a splash page that disappears after the background page is loaded like most apps do?)

The function I use to logout in another logoutViewController is:

```
// Should be the first in the stack
MyViewController *loginController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

if (loginController)
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:loginController animated:YES];
}
else
{
    NSMutableArray *controllers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    loginController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [controllers addObject:loginController];
    [controllers addObjectsFromArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:controllers];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The top if statement is always called and never runs into else. But the myViewController won't load after say I had the app on my phone or simulator for 24 hours.  It works fine if you do it right after logging in though. Why won't myViewController load correctly? How do I force that to happen?

Comment: I am actually not sure why this is happening; everything should work; can you try returning 'YES' from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` API?

Comment: it appears sometimes that the app doesn't load myViewController and stops on the myNavigationController and doesn't load the controller?

Comment: So `MyNavigationController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController`? Also, did you return YES from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?

Comment: what will return yest do?

Comment: actually i have return yes ste

Comment: @chris I would be very surprised if myViewController is not being loaded; can you put some NSLogs into the viewDidLoad to confirm?  Also, you say myViewController has a blue background - how is that set, in code or in storyboard?

Comment: I made the myNavigationController have a blue background so that I could tell that is what was being set.  It appears that myViewController doesn't get loaded after like 24 hours (but it loads fine when I run it originally). Why would that happen?

Comment: Added an update that logs out of my app and sends it back to the root. See above.

Comment: @chris As far as I know, a navigation controller must always have a root view controller.  So `loginController` will always exist (which is consistent with your observed path through the `logoutViewController` code).  Popping to viewController[0] is the same as `popToRootViewController`.  But (sorry if this is obvious) popping to a view controller will not cause it to run `viewDidLoad`.  Is that what you mean by "the rootViewController never gets fired"?

Comment: Yes so how do you get it to run viewDidLoad?

Comment: You should use a different method to achieve the same results: `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`, for example.